# How can i connect my zk teco k30 device with singnaling to my pc using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, fingerprint, zkemkeeper

Right now i am using this code for connecting my device with my pc using c# .
i want to connect my device with my system and generate a new signal with my device to pc in c#, and i want to store my data in my window form design and when time will come for finger print then i put my finger on my device and they catch my finger and show my finger scan in window fomr in picture box and then data will store in my database. i use SqlServer database.
Thanks in Advance.

```
 bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(ipaddress, port);   // 4370 is port no of attendance machine
            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                IDtextBox1.Enabled = true;
                  name_textBox2.Enabled = true;
                 designation_textBox3.Enabled = true;
                string title = "ZK Teco K30 Device.";
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Established.", title);
 bool ret = axCZKEM1.ReadAllGLogData(1);
                if (ret)
                {
                    int a = 0;
                    int b = 0;
                    int c = 0;
                    int d = 0;
                    int ee = 0;
                    int f = 0;
                    int g = 0;
                    int h = 0;
                    int i = 0;
                    int j = 0;
                    int k = 0;
                    int l = 0;
                    int m = 0;
                    int n = 0;
                    int o = 0;

                    while (axCZKEM1.GetAllGLogData(1, ref a, ref b, ref c, ref k, ref l, ref d,
                        ref m, ref ee, ref f, ref g))
                    {
                        count++;

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the finger on the device, but you cant display the image at your windows form. Because, what you get is the template not the actual finger image. Template is nothing but a encrypted value of collection of features of the fingerprint.